# Javamail Content-Type

Tags: image, jakarta-mail, content-type, multipart

I'm trying to send an Email via javamail adding embedded Images and an Outlook Invation which should be displayed showing up the buttons to accept/decline .... To make the buttons show up, i have to set the Content-Type of the MimeMultipart to related.

```
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
```

Once this is done, the embedded Pictures wont show up again.
To Display the embedded images it should be alternative.

I have send myself a Mail from Outlook containing an Image as well as a invation to a meeting.

When I check the header there, it says:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    boundary="_005_CCF531A072806F489D02A6DD2CF322A01D88EEA2de35s004hst42wp_";
    type="multipart/alternative"
```

I have already tried to set the Content-Type adding Parameters (type, charset ...) but it seems like their just getting ignored when sending the message. Here is the Method which I am calling to create the Message Part:

```
private Message generateMessage() throws Exception
{
    Configuration conf = Configuration.getInstance();
    // Get system properties
    Properties props = System.getProperties();

    // Setup mail server
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", conf.getProperty(Configuration.MAIL_SERVER));

    // Get session
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    // Create the message
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

    // Fill its headers
    message.setSubject(this.subject);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
    Address[] replyTo = new Address[]{new InternetAddress(replyEmail)};
    message.setReplyTo(replyTo);

    // Create a related multi-part to combine the parts
    MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

    // Create your new message part
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // ADD IMAGES
    multipart = attachImages(multipart);

    // ADD CALENDAR-FILE        
    multipart = attachCalendarFile(multipart);

    // Set Content-Type
    ContentType ct = new ContentType(message.getContentType());
    ct.setParameter("charset", "utf-8");
    ct.setParameter("type", "multipart/alternative");

    // Set Multipart-Content to Message including the Content-Type
    message.setContent(multipart, ct.toString());

    return message;
}
```

The output of message.writeTo(System.out); is the following:

```
From: mail@sender.com
Reply-To: noreply@recipient.com
Message-ID: <1150322817.1.1397725164700.JavaMail.User@MacBooks-mailserver.local>
Subject: test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; 
boundary="----=_Part_0_72769750.1397725164655"

------=_Part_0_72769750.1397725164655
```

Is there any chance to make it work with embedded images AND invations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google search led me here, so for future searchers:

@bill-shannon is of course correct. However, please save yourself the trouble of figuring out the low level Mime RFC stuff, and just use something like [Simple Java Mail](https://www.simplejavamail.org/) (open source) which figures out which structure suits best based on the input you provide. You can [interactively explore all the possible structures](https://www.simplejavamail.org/rfc-compliant.html#section-explore-multipart) Simple Java Mail can come up with. Disclaimer: I maintain this library (but I actually came across this SO question in my research into including voting buttons in emails for Outlook :) )

In your case you would use the following. First produce a Calendar content string, using something like [ical4j](https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j):

```
Calendar icsCalendar = new Calendar();
icsCalendar.getProperties().add(new ProdId("-//Events Calendar//iCal4j 1.0//EN"));
icsCalendar.getProperties().add(Version.VERSION_2_0);

(..) // add attendees, organizer, end/start date and whatever else you need

// Produce calendar string
ByteArrayOutputStream bOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
new CalendarOutputter().output(icsCalendar, bOutStream);
String yourICalEventString = bOutStream.toString("UTF-8")
```

Then use Simple Java Mail's email builder to set the Calendar content alongside everything else such as images:

```
Email email = EmailBuilder
   .startingBlank()
   .withCalendarText(CalendarMethod.REQUEST, yourICalEventString)
   .everythingElseLikeImagesHeadersAttachmentsEtcEtc()
   .buildEmail();
```

Then send using the mailer builder:

```
MailerBuilder
  .withSMTPServer("server", 25, "username", "password")
  .buildMailer()
  .sendMail(email);
```

Then depending on whether you provided text, html attachments or other things, Simple Java Mail will select the appropriate Mime structure with mixed/related/alternative parts.

Answer (score 1):

There's three types of multiparts, each used for a different purpose.  In some cases you might need to use all three.  For example, a message with a calendar attachment, html content using images, and equivalent plain text content, might have a structure such as this:

```
multipart/mixed
  multipart/alternative
    text/plain
    multipart/related
      text/html
      image/jpeg
  text/calendar
```